# Почему в функции console.log срабатывает, а show() нет?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть [демо интернет-магазин](http://motors.likemedia.by/shop/). Не могу понять, почему в конструкции, которая реагирует на триггер сравнения товаров в тумбе - значок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] в конструкции console.log работает, а show(); нет?

```
$('body').bind('yith_woocompare_render_table', function() {
    $('#fix-bot').show();
    console.log('woocompare');
  });
```

Блок fix-bot точно существует и находится в скрытом виде (display:none;), т.к. при нажатии на кнопку добавить в корзину - он благополучно появляется

Comment: display:block работет вроде как я посмотрю)
добавьте еще z-index:50000;

Comment: @sivik_xes там сработала вот такая конструкция `$("#fix-bot", window.parent.document).show();`